# Microsoft Office on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I used to have Microsoft Office on MacBook Pro. Now I bought a MacBook Air.

What version of Office should I download and where from? I need to open my files that I created in my previous Mac and of course the Office that works offline.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Apps from Microsoft? Have you tried simply copying the apps from your old MacBook?

Comment: Where did you source that previous version? Office is available in several 'flavours', either directly from Microsoft or from the App Store. The App Store version will automatically be available to you on a new Mac with the same Apple ID. Versions obtained directly from MS you will need to check with them for authorisation.

Comment: If you want a free office clone that will open your files, try LibreOffice.

Comment: Have Office365 (work account) on my macbook air and also Numbers, Pages & Keynote - which open and save all the word excel and powerpoint files anyway.

Comment: The Apple Migration Assistant.app is *designed* to transfer all your apps, settings, documents, pictures... **everything.** Is there some reason you didn't  use that when moving from one Mac to another?

Answer (score 0):

My parents office 356 is from 2010, and is installed through a DVD
newer versions are installed via online.
do you have a product key or account with Microsoft 365 license?
if so, go to [office.com](https://www.office.com) and sign in with the account with Microsoft 365 license. then, click get office, or download office, or some button like that. when finished installing, sign in with same account